# What does it mean when a C# function parameter contains `= null`?

Tags: c#, .net, optional-parameters

I'm going through an [MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and see this line of code at the beginning of a function:

```
private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(object selectedDepartment = null)
```

After testing it out, I can see that the function works, but I do not understand *how* the function parameter works.  What does `object selectedDepartment = null` do?

I have done a general internet search and have not yet been able to locate an  answer.

I guess my question really has two facets:

1. What does the `= null` portion of the parameter do?
2. Is it something that *can* be done but not necessarily *should* be done?

Comment: The `= null` portion of the argument makes it an optional parameter, which will supply a default value of null for that parameter. It can be valid if you want polymorphic methods that allow for optional parameters.

Comment: Nitpick on terminology - what you've shown is a *parameter*. The parameters are always at the place where the method is declared - the *arguments* are always at the place where the method is called, providing the values. It's the same for generic type parameters/type arguments - in the declaration of `List<T>`, `T` is a type parameter. When you talk about a specific concrete list type, e.g. `List<string> x = new List<string>();` here `string` is the type argument.

Comment: It's not a nitpick if it suggests better language use. I'll update the language in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It means that that parameter will be null, unless you *decide* to pass something. So in other words, its optional.
2. It can be done, and there is nothing wrong with it. Its pretty common practice.

Comment: Although other answers go deeper into explaining the first part of my question, this is a compact answer and addresses both parts of my question.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you can call

```
PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList()
```

or

```
PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList("something")
```

both because compiler will convert the first one to

```
PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(null)
```

This feature is called [Optional Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

I suggest you to read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

the `= null` is the default value of the parameter, it is the functional equivalent as if you had

```
private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList()
{
    PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(null);
}

private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(object selectedDepartment)
{
     //Your code here.
}
```

So if you can call the function with no parameters `PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList()` it will call the 1 perameter version and pass in null.

Comment: it is not equivalent to that, it is a compile time action and does not generate a new function signature!

Answer (score 0):

This sets the argument to a default value (if not provided) and prevents a compile time error if the argument is not provided. See:

[Setting the default value of a C# Optional Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729639/setting-the-default-value-of-a-c-sharp-optional-parameter)

Basically this argument is now optional so you can call the function in either of these two ways:

```
PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList() //selectedDepartment will be set to null as it is not provided
```

**OR**

```
PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(myObject) //selectedDepartment will become myObject
```