# C# Optional Array Parameter for Class

Tags: c#, class, optional-parameters

I know this can be done using `null` so I have a workaround for that, but I was wondering if there was a better way that I can have an optional `int[]` parameter for a class?

```
class PriceLevels
{
    public int[] priceLevels { get; }
    private readonly int[] defaultPriceLevels = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public PriceLevels(int[] newPriceLevels = defaultPriceLevels)
    {
        priceLevels = newPriceLevels;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error saying it is an invalid expression `defaultPriceLevels` must be constant. How can I fix this?

One workaround that I can thing of is this, but I don't really like the solution

```
class PriceLevels
{
    public int[] priceLevels { get; }
    private readonly int[] defaultPriceLevels = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public PriceLevels(int[] newPriceLevels = null)
    {
        if(newPriceLevels == null) 
            priceLevels = defaultPriceLevels;
        else 
            priceLevels = newPriceLevels;
    }
}
```

Comment: use overloading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an empty array as default value of an optional parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480382/passing-an-empty-array-as-default-value-of-an-optional-parameter)

Comment: Why your `priceLevels` property has no setter?

Comment: Default Value by assignment for a function's input value can be the same as "const" assignment rules……So yours cannot be implemented directly until now.

Comment: @S.Akbari You're probably right. However, if the idea is to only allow `priceLevels` to be set on initialization (hence the default value as a fallback), then it's valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the default value of a C# Optional Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729639/setting-the-default-value-of-a-c-sharp-optional-parameter)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A better design all together would be to have **2 constructors** ([constructor overload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5555715/6400526)) one that gets a `int[]` and another that doesn't:

```
class PriceLevels
{
    public int[] priceLevels { get; set; }
    private readonly int[] defaultPriceLevels = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public PriceLevels()
    {
        priceLevels = defaultPriceLevels;
    }

    public PriceLevels(int[] newPriceLevels)
    {
       priceLevels = newPriceLevels;
    }
}
```

If not, don't know if i'd call this "better" but you can use the [**`params` keyword**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params):

```
class PriceLevels
{
    public int[] priceLevels { get; set; }
    private readonly int[] defaultPriceLevels = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public PriceLevels(params int[] newPriceLevels)
    {
        priceLevels = newPriceLevels.Length == 0 ? defaultPriceLevels : newPriceLevels;
    }
}
```

Also, depending on design, I'm not convinced that it is `PriceLevels` responsibility to decide what the default values are and maybe it should get it as a dependency in any case - See [SOLID](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) and **[Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)**. Then you'd have only 1 constructor:

```
class PriceLevels
{
    public int[] priceLevels { get; set; }

    public PriceLevels(int[] newPriceLevels)
    {
       priceLevels = newPriceLevels;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the `priceLevels` property should has setter.

Comment: The null-coalescing operator on its own makes it 'better'!

Comment: Thanks, I think I will probably go with your final suggestion and re-think my structure. Also, curious about this setter thing... why is it necessary that I have a setter (even if it is private) if all I am doing is setting that value upon initialization of the class?

Comment: @Adjit - Cubicle.Jockey comment below about the setters.

Comment: @Gilad, I don't think the first part with `params` works - if you call it w/o parameters, you still receive **empty array**, not `null`.

Comment: @IvanStoev - correct. Tested and you are right. Missed it. Fixed the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

You can overload your constructor.

```
class PriceLevels
{
    public int[] priceLevels { get; private set; }
    private readonly int[] defaultPriceLevels = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public PriceLevels()
    {
        priceLevels = defaultPriceLevels;
    }

    public PriceLevels(int[] newPriceLevels)
    {
       priceLevels = newPriceLevels;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the priceLevels property should has setter.

Comment: Added a private setter. Thanks.

Comment: If C# 6.0 the private set is unnecessary if the value is set in the constructor only.

Answer (score 7):

You could create another constructor with no parameters that would just pass your defaultPriceLevels variable to the constructor you already have? You'd have to change the variable to static too.

e.g.

```
class PriceLevels
{
    public int[] priceLevels { get; }
    private static int[] defaultPriceLevels = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public PriceLevels(int[] newPriceLevels = null)
    {
        if (newPriceLevels == null) priceLevels = defaultPriceLevels;
        else priceLevels = newPriceLevels;
    }

    public PriceLevels() : this(defaultPriceLevels)
    { }
}
```

Comment: @DongWei You surely can do it. Try it in linqpad.

Comment: ：Sorry I should paste what I said to OP instead of you :)

Comment: Liked this solution but you shouldn't make the `newPriceLevels` optional in one of the Constructors, that in my view has no benefit +1

Answer (score 7):

Another option in the Crowd :), which is closest to your original code

```
class PriceLevels
{
  public int[] priceLevels { get; set; }

  private readonly int[] defaultPriceLevels = { 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

  public PriceLevels(int[] newPriceLevels = null)
  {
     priceLevels = newPriceLevels ?? defaultPriceLevels;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just create an overload of the constructor! It can be really easily done with one line of code!

```
public PriceLevels() : this(defaultPriceLevels) { }
```

Then, remove the default parameter value from the original constructor:

```
public PriceLevels(int[] newPriceLevels)
```

Actually, you also need to declare `defaultPriceLevels` as `static`. Hopefully you don't mind that.

Answer (score 3):

Optional array parameters are not possible in C#. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd264739.aspx)

> Each optional parameter has a default value as part of its definition.
>   If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used. 
>   A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where
>     ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of
>     the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

Therefore a "workaround" has to be used. Either check for null (as you suggested) or you can use a default constructor.